# Export Query from Access to an Excel Template

Tags: excel, templates, ms-access, export-to-excel, vba

I have a query that runs on a specified day of the week. On that day if any record is marked "Needs Ordered" then an orderform window will open with a command button. The command button should export the query data to a excel template (already formatted the way it should look) and then attach to an email template to send. I can get the query to attach to the email I just can't seem to figure out how to get it to use the excel template instead of creating a new excel workbook each time. Any suggestions on what to try?

```
Dim myolapp As Object 
Dim myitem As Object 

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "BoxOrder", "C:\Users\Database Design\Desktop\BoxOrder.xlsx", True 

Set myolapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") myolapp.Session.Logon 
Set myitem = myolapp.CreateItemFromTemplate("F:\BOX ORDER FOR PC CONNECTION.oft") 
Set myAttachments = myitem.attachments 

myAttachments.Add "C:\Users\Database Design\Desktop\BoxOrder.xlsx"
myitem.Display 'or send 
DoCmd.Close acForm, "OrderForm"
```

The `BoxOrder` query:

```sql
SELECT '' AS [Quantity Needed], [BoxOrder].[Box Size], [BoxOrder].Comments, 
       [BoxOrder].[Certified/Stamped Boxes], [BoxOrder].[Box Type] 
FROM BoxOrder;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The `TemplateFile` parameter of `DoCmd.OutputTo` is only for HTML (and similar) export.

There are two possibilities after using `DoCmd.OutputTo` or `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`. This can all be done with VBA:

- Open exported file and template file, copy & paste the data from export to template, save as new file.
- Open exported file, apply the formatting with VBA.
  Use the Excel macro recorder to give you a head start.

It depends on the complexity of your template, which one is better.

Comment: The template is extremely basic. The first row has all the headers I need in place. Nothing else. The end user that will be using this is not very familiar with excel so I am trying to make it as easy as possible for him.

Comment: Then you should use `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, ... , HasFieldNames := True`. If necessary, edit your query columns to have the column names you want ( `SELECT Fieldname AS [Column Header], ...` ). Then you probably won't need any further formatting. @Mouse

Comment: what if I need to add one column that I do not have a field for. I need to add Quantity Needed to the excel spreadsheet and the user will manually enter the quantity. If I have to, I guess I can make another window that opens asking for the quantities. I was just trying to avoid having several windows opening to send the order. @Andre451

Comment: @Mouse: you can simply add a constant, empty column to your query: `SELECT ..., "" AS [Quantity Needed] FROM ...` . This will generate an empty column in Excel. Or if the user who creates the export must fill this out, have a column `[Quantity Needed]`, this will become a parameter that is asked when opening or exporting the query.

Comment: @Mouse: If your spreadsheet is empty, then your query "BoxOrder" does not return any records.

Comment: @Mouse: and you must use `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12` when exporting to xlsx.

Comment: It put it as a new sheet at the end of the workbook. So it does work. It just doesn't insert my Quantity Needed field. Just changed it to excel 12

Comment: @Mouse: please add the SQL of your "BoxOrder" query to the question.

Comment: @Mouse: It seems you have a **table** "BoxOrder" and a **query** "BoxOrder", so it's exporting the table. Rename the query to e.g. "qryBoxorder" and export that.

Comment: nope the query is BoxOrder and the tables name is Boxes

Comment: @Mouse: But your query says `SELECT ... FROM BoxOrder`. You're confusing me. :)

Comment: This code is in the record source for the BoxOrder subform. When the order form opens the BoxOrder Query subform is display on it. If i change it to my table name then the query doesn't run.

Comment: @Mouse: You need to have a saved & named query to export with `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`. Create a new query (if necessary) with the SQL from your question, save it as "qryBoxOrder", and use this name in `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`.

Comment: I do, I have my table Boxes, Query BoxOrder, BoxOrder Query Subform, and a OrderForm.

Comment: @Mouse: Then you must put `'' AS [Quantity Needed], ` into your query BoxOrder, not into the subform recordsource. Only then will the column be exported.